# Database session support in nodejs/express

Tags: javascript, database, session, node.js, session-cookies

Does expressjs/nodejs have support (via a module?) for database sessions? I come from the world of PHP/CodeIgniter and I've enjoyed the features of storing session data in a mysql database table.

Is this approach used with nodejs web apps?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes.

#### Redis

- https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis

#### MySQL

- <s>https://github.com/mren/connect-session-mysql</s> Broken Link
- <s>https://github.com/CarnegieLearning/connect-mysql-session</s> Old, Unsupported
- https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session

#### PostgreSQL

- https://github.com/jebas/connect-pg

#### MongoDB

- https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo
- https://github.com/bartt/connect-session-mongo
- https://github.com/donpark/session-mongoose
- https://github.com/masylum/connect-mongodb

#### Memcached

- https://github.com/balor/connect-memcached

#### CouchDB

- https://github.com/tdebarochez/connect-couchdb
- https://github.com/eldios/connect-cradle

#### Riak

- https://github.com/frank06/connect-riak

#### SQLite

- https://github.com/tnantoka/connect-sqlite
- https://github.com/pkrumins/supermarket-cart

#### File-based

- https://github.com/odogono/connect-session-file
- https://github.com/tnantoka/connect-fs

#### Kyoto-cabinet

- https://github.com/kazupon/connect-kyoto

#### Azure

- https://github.com/pofallon/connect-bluesky

#### nStore

- https://github.com/creationix/nstore-session

#### node-dirty

- https://github.com/mmichelli/connect-dirty

#### VOC (?)

- https://github.com/triAGENS/SessionVoc-Connect.js

It's quite simple to implement your own, [see documentation here](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html).