# node.js passport autentification with sqlite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, passport.js

Its possible use node.js + passport and sqlite database with session? All example only with mongoDb. I want collect all data in sqlite.

Comment: it's about database backed session store. checkout this question [Database session support in nodejs/express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136774/database-session-support-in-nodejs-express)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Below is an example of using [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) to create a [SQLite](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) backed [login strategy](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/). Express specific initialization has been omitted.

This example assumes you have a database with the following users table:

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "username" TEXT,
    "password" TEXT, -- sha256 hash of the plain-text password
    "salt" TEXT -- salt that is appended to the password before it is hashed
)
```

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

var db = new sqlite3.Database('./database.sqlite3');

// ...

function hashPassword(password, salt) {
  var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
  hash.update(password);
  hash.update(salt);
  return hash.digest('hex');
}

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  db.get('SELECT salt FROM users WHERE username = ?', username, function(err, row) {
    if (!row) return done(null, false);
    var hash = hashPassword(password, row.salt);
    db.get('SELECT username, id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', username, hash, function(err, row) {
      if (!row) return done(null, false);
      return done(null, row);
    });
  });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  return done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  db.get('SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE id = ?', id, function(err, row) {
    if (!row) return done(null, false);
    return done(null, row);
  });
});

// ...

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/good-login',
                                                    failureRedirect: '/bad-login' }));
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try when i return home.

Comment: Trying to use this sample I get an error that 'LocalStrategy' is not defined! How do I solve that?

Comment: While this covers login, how would you create a new account?

Comment: @nivhab `npm i passport-local` and `const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not too late to add-on @tim-cooper answer.
Tim done a good job on explaining the login part for passport login using sqlite.

Hereby I attach the sample code for other who like to know how to create a new account via passport-local (sqlite).

If anyone would like to find the complete code sample for passport-local (login, logout, create, profile). You can refer to this github link: https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example

```
var express = require('express');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./database.sqlite3');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/new', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('signup');
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var salt = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  crypto.pbkdf2(req.body.password, salt, 310000, 32, 'sha256', function(err, hashedPassword) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    
    db.run('INSERT INTO users (username, hashed_password, salt, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', [
      req.body.username,
      hashedPassword,
      salt,
      req.body.name
    ], function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      
      var user = {
        id: this.lastID.toString(),
        username: req.body.username,
        displayName: req.body.name
      };
      req.login(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```